# Return multiple values from one reference id

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

is it possible to have an excel formula that would create the output table below?

```
initial data:
╔════════════╦═════════╦══════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ product id ║  item   ║ size ║ price ║ size totals ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║        123 ║ apple   ║ s    ║    34 ║         100 ║
║        982 ║ orange  ║ m    ║    21 ║         120 ║
║        421 ║ banana  ║ s    ║    12 ║          98 ║
║        123 ║ apple2  ║ s    ║    43 ║         109 ║
║        421 ║ banana2 ║ m    ║    65 ║          50 ║
║       8767 ║ lemon   ║ l    ║    11 ║          25 ║
║       8767 ║ lemon2  ║ m    ║    33 ║           2 ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩══════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

```
desire output:
╔════════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦════════╦═══════════════╗
║ product id ║ item1  ║ price ║ item2   ║ price ║ size1 ║ size totals ║ size 2 ║ size totals 2 ║
╠════════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬════════╬═══════════════╣
║        123 ║ apple  ║    34 ║ apple2  ║    43 ║ s     ║         100 ║ s      ║           109 ║
║        982 ║ orange ║    21 ║         ║       ║ m     ║         120 ║        ║               ║
║        421 ║ banana ║    12 ║ banana2 ║    65 ║ s     ║          98 ║ m      ║            50 ║
╚════════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Note: sample output is shown for just three output records because they are sufficient to illustrate the pattern.  Lemon and lemon2 are included in the initial data just to illustrate more examples of potential input variation.

Comment: Is there anything to deduce about lemon being excluded?  prod_id is 4 digits vs. 3, it's the only item with size l, and lemon2 is the only item that has no price.  Are any of those things the reason there isn't an output record for it, or did you simply decide that the example output was long enough to illustrate the point?  Where do the size totals come from?

Comment: Equally, "price < 35 and price not null" would also work; as well as "no 'l' or number in item". Need more info about criteria.

Comment: @fixer1234 lemon2 is excluded for no reason. like you said decided "that the example output was long enough to illustrate the point". SORRY! there should be a column next to the "prices" on the "initial data" table that would include those "size totals"

Comment: I would reconsider the output design, it wont scale and will make it difficult to read and analyze the meaning of your data.  Writing formulas based on that layout will be almost impossible.

Instead, I would try to add a new column e.g. "item group" containing values like apples, oranges, bananas.  With the data still in a clean table format, the users can easily sort/filter/summary or create pivot tables to analyze and compare the values.

Comment: @MikeHoney thank you for your suggestion, however this is what the users are asking for, hence it's now a business decision and i have no choice but to figure out a way to implemented.

Comment: Perhaps they should reconsider that decision. The new design will take a lot of effort to create and maintain - is your time free? Also the users will likely miss important trends and comparisons in the data (eg very difficult to compare the price of apple1 with apple6), leading to making poor business decisions (oh we didn't notice that apple6 was twice the price of apple1).

Comment: Agree with @MikeHoney. This is just plain bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Your table conflicts with two "design rules" for tables (I just formulated them - but I tried for distill rules/principles that explain why your table design is not very good):

- you can read any row/column combination without (too much) scanning along the row.
- all data that is needed to understand a row, is placed als much left in the table as possible.

If you would shift the *item* as a second column (second rule), this would make the table more compact, better readable and also ready to automatically create using [Pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-MY/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

I create a Pivot table base don your sample data. I think this illustrates that this design is compact, and easily created in Excel (some texts such as "Waarden" ("Values") are in Dutch, because of my language version).

[image]

I created this Pivot table with the following fields:

- **Rows**: product id, item and size
- **Columns**: Values
- **Values**: Count of size, Avarage of price and Sum of total

Also, I removes the sub totals and reverted the Pivot table layout to "Classical layout".